# Xamarin Android WebView not opening links in browser once SetWebViewClient is called

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

I have a simple webview that is loading some locally stored HTML. There are plain vanilla links in the HTML, like `<a href="https://google.com"/>`. When a user taps on one of these links, I want the device browser to open.

This is the default behaviour for an Android webview and seems to work fine, however as soon as I call the `webView.SetWebViewClient(webViewClient)` method, this default behaviour stops.

I've tried overriding the `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method(s) in my implementation of the `WebViewClient` class to open the browser myself, but these methods are never getting called.

To summarise, like this, links in my HTML will open in the browser:

```
webView = new WebView(Activity);

//var webViewClient = new WebViewClient();
//webView.SetWebViewClient(webViewClient);

webView.LoadData(myHTML, "text/html", null);
```

But as soon as I uncomment those two lines, the links will open within the WebView.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your ShouldOverrideUrlLoading method is not being called in your class as I don't have all your code to look at.  So, I put together a fully working example where you can control how the links are opened--whether in your webview view or another Android browser activity.  I hope it helps!

**WebView.axml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/WebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webviewMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**testwebview.html** ("Assets/html/testwebview.html" in project)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebView Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select a link...</h1>
    <br />
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <br />
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebViewCustomOverrideActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Content;

namespace XamdroidMaster.Activities {

    [Activity(Label = "Custom WebView Testing", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class WebViewCustomOverrideActivity : Activity {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.WebView);
            WebView wv = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webviewMain);

            MyWebViewClient myWebViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();
            wv.SetWebViewClient(myWebViewClient);

            wv.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/testwebview.html");  // "Assets/html/testwebview.html" in project
        }

    }

    public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient {

        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url) {

            if (url.ToLower().Contains("google.com")) {
                // Let my WebView load the page
                return false;
            }

            // For all other links, launch another Activity that handles URLs
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
            view.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            return true;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The Xamarin Android not using XAML